# Resource not found error on running move_group.launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

On launch the move_group.launch, following error comes up:

```
raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: [cool1000_moveit_config]
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/asimov3/Ros/cool1000_ros_experimental/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks"
```

---

I have checked the launch file commands and ensured that the files which the commands are looking for exists. Identified that the error is thrown from this line:

```
  <!-- Trajectory Execution Functionality -->
  <include ns="move_group" file="$(find cool1000_moveit_config)/launch/trajectory_execution.launch.xml" if="$(arg allow_trajectory_execution)">
    <arg name="moveit_manage_controllers" value="true" />
    <arg name="moveit_controller_manager" value="cool1000" unless="$(arg fake_execution)"/>
    <arg name="moveit_controller_manager" value="fake" if="$(arg fake_execution)"/>
  </include>
```

Could anyone help me out with removing this error?

Revised finding:
On tracing the error I see that its generated from this file: `trajectory_execution.launch.xml` from the following line:

```
  <!-- Load the robot specific controller manager; this sets the moveit_controller_manager ROS parameter -->
  <arg name="moveit_controller_manager" default="cool1000" />
  <include file="$(find cool1000_moveit_config)/launch/$(arg moveit_controller_manager)_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml"/>
```

And further tracing lead me here in `cool1000_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml`:

```
<launch>
      <arg name="moveit_controller_manager"
       default="moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager"/>
  <param name="moveit_controller_manager"
         value="$(arg moveit_controller_manager)"/>

  <rosparam file="$(find [cool1000_moveit_config])/config/controllers.yaml"/>

</launch>
```

Here the `controllers.yaml` file is inside the `config` folder. Then where should the problem come from?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208536/resource-not-found-error-on-running-move_group.launch/) by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-05**:
Can you add the output of `rospack find cool1000_moveit_config`, run in the same terminal as where you try to launch `move_group.launch`?

**Comment by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) on 2015-05-05**:
asimov3@asimov3:~/Ros/cool1000_ros_experimental$ rospack find cool1000_moveit_config
/home/asimov3/Ros/cool1000_ros_experimental/src/cool1000_moveit_config

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-05**:
Make sure you have no typos in your launch file. Other than that, this should work. You could try a `rospack profile` and try again (I doubt that will change anything though, as the `rospack find ..` command already worked).

**Comment by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) on 2015-05-05**:
Hi gvdhoorn, thanks for your reply, I rechecked it and dint find any typos. However got a bit in detail. But still stuck. Have updated the question with the revised findings. Do you find any problem till here that would cause the error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-05**:
For future questions: please format console copy/pastes and source code (such as these launch file excerpts) using the *preformatted text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> And further tracing lead me here in `cool1000_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml`:

> ```
> <launch>
>   ..
>   <rosparam file="$(find [cool1000_moveit_config])/config/controllers.yaml" />
> </launch>
> ```

If that is really what is there, then you should remove the square brackets (`[` and `]`). They should not be there, unless the folder is really named `[cool1000_moveit_config]`, so the name does include the square brackets).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0